# PHP Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error when I try to log in to my site and I have no idea how to fix it. What is missing? Someone edit this thing for me!

PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in client_config.php on line 147

I have tried almost all other solutions posted on this forum but none seems to work for me. Actually almost all other errors are coming from this same file so anyone who can spot any errors in the code can help. Any guidance will be highly appreciated. I am currently logged out of my site until this is fixed.

PS. I have no programming knowledge.

```
<?php
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
$GLOBALdatabase_cf = array();
$GLOBALdatabase_cf['host']          = 'localhost';
$GLOBALdatabase_cf['username']      = 'myusername';
$GLOBALdatabase_cf['password']      = 'password';
$GLOBALdatabase_cf['database']      = 'database';
$GLOBALdatabase_cf['prefix']        = 'mu_';

$GLOBALdatabase_cf['cookieName']    = 'cookiename';
$GLOBALdatabase_cf['cookieKey']     = 'cookiekey';

$connect = @mysql_connect($GLOBALdatabase_cf['host'] , $GLOBALdatabase_cf['username'] , $GLOBALdatabase_cf['password']);
if (!$connect)
{
    die ("Couldn't make connection.");
}
@mysql_select_db($GLOBALdatabase_cf['database'], $connect) or die ("Couldn't select database");
list($admin_domain_name) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select domain_name from system where site_type = 'backend'")); 

$domain_name = stripit($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlParse = parse_url($url);
$path = explode('/',$urlParse ['path']);
$site_URL= get_base_url($host_this);  
$siteUrl = stripit($site_URL);

if (!defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');    
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');  

if (!defined('ROOT_DIR_C') )
define('ROOT_DIR_C', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

if (!defined('BASE_URL_C') )
define('BASE_URL_C', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR_C))));
define('DOWNLOAD_URL', BASE_URL_C . 'orders/download?f=');

$upload_download_dir = '/home/essaycoachonline/crownresearchcenter.com/uploads/';

list($curr_symbol) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select sys_curr from settings")); // currency symbol
list($admin_site_email) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select site_email from system where site_type = 'backend'")); 
list($admin_site_name) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select site_name from system where site_type = 'backend'")); 
list($admin_site_base_price) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select base_price from system where site_type = 'backend'")); 

$sql_site_settings = "select * from system where url = '$siteUrl'";
$result_site_settings = mysql_query($sql_site_settings) or die(mysql_error());
$row_site_settings = mysql_fetch_array($result_site_settings);

list($site_support) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select email from mu_members where role = 'sub_admin'")); 
$site_email= $row_site_settings['site_email'];
$admin_email =$row_site_settings['admin_email'];
$basePrice =$row_site_settings['base_price'];
$price_override = $row_site_settings['price_override'];

define ("SITE_HOST_NAME", $domain_name);
define ("SITE_NAME", $row_site_settings['site_name']);

$academicEmail= $admin_site_email;
define ("ACADEMIC_SITE_NAME",$admin_site_name);


$user_registration = 1;  // set 0 or 1
$writer_registration = 0;

define("COOKIE_TIME_OUT", 1); //specify cookie timeout in days (default is 10 days)
define('SALT_LENGTH', 9); // salt for password

/* Specify user levels */
define ("ADMIN_LEVEL", 5);
define ("WRITER_LEVEL", 3);
define ("CLIENT_LEVEL", 2);
define ("USER_LEVEL", 1);
define ("GUEST_LEVEL", 0);

function page_protect() {
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');// Africa/Nairobi
}
global $GLOBALdatabase_cf; 
/* Secure against Session Hijacking by checking user agent */
if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        logout();
        exit;
    }
}
// before we allow sessions, we need to check authentication key - ckey and ctime stored in database
/* If session not set, check for cookies set by Remember me */
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['username']) ) 
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
    /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

    $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['id']);
    $rs_ctime = mysql_query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `mu_members` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    list($ckey,$ctime) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
    // coookie expiry
    if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

        logout();
        }
/* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
/* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

     if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['username']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
          session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

         date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');// Africa/Nairobi

          $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'] ;
          $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];

        /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */  
          list($user_level) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select user_level from mu_members where id='$_SESSION[id]'"));
          $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;    

    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
       } else {
       logout();
       }
  } else {
    header("Location: ../login/");
    exit();
    }
}
}

function filter($data) {
if(is_scalar($data))
{
   $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
}
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

if(is_scalar($data))
{   
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); **--->Line 147**
}   
    return $data;
}

function EncodeURL($url)
{
$new = strtolower(ereg_replace(' ','_',$url));
return($new);
}

function DecodeURL($url)
{
$new = ucwords(ereg_replace('_',' ',$url));
return($new);
}

function ChopStr($str, $len) 
{
    if (strlen($str) < $len)
        return $str;

    $str = substr($str,0,$len);
    if ($spc_pos = strrpos($str," "))
            $str = substr($str,0,$spc_pos);

    return $str . "...";
}   

function isNum($price){
return preg_match("/[^0-9]/", "",$price)? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function isEmail($email){
  return preg_match('/^\S+@[\w\d.-]{2,}\.[\w]{2,6}$/iU', $email) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function isUserID($username)
{
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]{5,20}$/i', $username)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }  

function isURL($url) 
{
    if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i', $url)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} 

function checkPwd($x,$y) 
{
if(empty($x) || empty($y) ) { return false; }
if (strlen($x) < 4 || strlen($y) < 4) { return false; }

if (strcmp($x,$y) != 0) {
 return false;
 } 
return true;
}

function GenPwd($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"; //no vowels

  $i = 0; 

  while ($i < $length) { 


    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);


    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}

function GenKey($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

  $i = 0; 

  while ($i < $length) { 


    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);


    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}
function rand_my_string( $length ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }
    return $str;
}

function logout()
{
global $GLOBALdatabase_cf;
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) || isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
mysql_query("update `mu_members` 
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
            where `id`='$_SESSION[id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
}           
/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['email']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['writer']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("username", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

$lg= 'You are now logged out';
header("Location: login/?sign=$lg");
}
// Password and salt generation
function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)     {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9);
    }
    else     {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 9);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}
function checkAdmin() { //admin

if($_SESSION['user_level'] == ADMIN_LEVEL) {
return 1;
} else { return 0 ;
}
}

function checkWriter() { //writer

if($_SESSION['user_level'] == WRITER_LEVEL) {
return 1;
} else { return 0 ;
}
}

function checkClient() { //client
if($_SESSION['user_level'] == CLIENT_LEVEL) {
return 1;
} else { return 0 ;
}
}

function ShortenText($text) {
        $chars = 30;
        $text = $text." ";
        $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
        $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' ')).'.....';

        return $text;

    }
//
function dateDiff($time1, $time2, $precision = 6) {

    // If not numeric then convert texts to unix timestamps
    if (!is_int($time1)) {
      $time1 = strtotime($time1);
    }
    if (!is_int($time2)) {
      $time2 = strtotime($time2);
    }

    // If time1 is bigger than time2
    // Then swap time1 and time2
   if ($time1 > $time2) {
     $ttime = $time1;
    $time1 = $time2;
     $time2 = $ttime;
    }

    // Set up intervals and diffs arrays
    $intervals = array('year','month','day','hour','minute','second');
    $diffs = array();

    // Loop thru all intervals
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
      // Set default diff to 0
      $diffs[$interval] = 0;
      // Create temp time from time1 and interval
      $ttime = strtotime("+1 " . $interval, $time1);
      // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
      while ($time2 >= $ttime) {
    $time1 = $ttime;
    $diffs[$interval]++;
    // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
    $ttime = strtotime("+1 " . $interval, $time1);
      }
    }

    $count = 0;
    $times = array();
    // Loop thru all diffs
    foreach ($diffs as $interval => $value) {
      // Break if we have needed precission
      if ($count >= $precision) {
    break;
      }
      // Add value and interval 
      // if value is bigger than 0
      if ($value > 0) {
    // Add s if value is not 1
    if ($value != 1) {
      $interval .= "s";
    }
    // Add value and interval to times array
    $times[] = $value . " " . $interval;
    $count++;
      }
    }
    // Return string with times
    return implode(", ", $times);
  }
//
function get_base_url()
    {
        /* protocol the website is using */
        $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"], 0, 5)) == 'https' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        /* returns /myproject/index.php */
        $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
        $directory = $path_parts['dirname'];

        $directory = ($directory == "/") ? "" : $directory;

        /* Returns localhost OR mysite.com */
        $host_this = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        return $protocol . $host_this ;
    }

function stripit ( $url ) {
    $url = trim($url);
    $url = preg_replace("/^(http:\/\/)*(www.)*/is", "", $url);
    $url = preg_replace("/\/.*$/is" , "" ,$url);
    return $url;
    }   
?>
```

Comment: The code is still in its original state, and the same error is still being produced when I try to login. http://prntscr.com/jkl06w

Comment: Also can you take a screenshot of the line `147` the error is talking about? (a photo)

Comment: Here it is http://prntscr.com/jkmzrr

Comment: The code is at it in the first instance. This was just me trying out some of the solutions listed on other threads but it did not work.

Comment: $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); ---->original line 147

Comment: This is the only error I have. I have uploaded all the three files. [link](https://ufile.io/06v5p), [link](https://ufile.io/l4nv6), [link](https://ufile.io/139wo)

Comment: Well, the client_config.php file says at line `147` this: `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);` which isn't what is found in the question code that you posted. Try then to use in `147` the code: `$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);` at let me know what errors are generated in the `error_log`.

Comment: I have updated line 147 as per your instructions [link](http://prntscr.com/jkp4nl). This is the new error [link](http://prntscr.com/jkp5i5)

Comment: No, I meant: remove the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function and replace it with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: New error:  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in client_config.php:147  Stack trace:  #0 /home/public_html/homeworkmaid/top_log_in.php(8): filter('Admin')
#1 /home/public_html/homeworkmaid/login/index.php(4): include('/home/filmnkyi/...')
#2 {main}  thrown in /client_config.php on line 147

Comment: Am using php 7.2

Comment: Great. And you tried to use mysqli extension in all your code as I see in the client_config.php you uploaded. We are close.

Comment: Yeah, Should I change the extensions to mysql or should they remain as they are? What's the next step?

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated you won't be able to use it. I am writing an answer .. one minute ... !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441842/php-warning-mysqli-real-escape-string-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null?noredirect=1#comment87916753_50441842) that you are using **PHP 7.2**, so you will have problems using any `mysql_` function because this extension is [deprecated since 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql).

**You should try using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.**

You showed in [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jkl06w) that you tried using `mysqli_real_escape_string` function in line `147` which takes two parameters: 1- the mysqli connection, 2- the string to escape (`$data`)

You did it like this: `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GLOBALS['$con'], $data);`

You have two problems here with `$_GLOBALS['$con']` it should be `$GLOBALS['con']` : the [GLOBALS variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) without the underscore `_` and the key without '$'.

So you should replace the line `147` with:

`$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['con'], $data);`

Also I don't know if GLOBALS variable is the safest way to get variables!

Comment: Done! Am still having other issues with this script. Will be adding more questions as they come up. Already added another: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452810/php-warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-null-given)